# Run shell script from Java Synchronously

Tags: java, bash, shell, synchronous

I am trying to execute a Bash Shell script from Java and it runs fine using this piece of code.

```
public void executeScript() {
    try {
        new ProcessBuilder("myscript.sh").start();
        System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code runs fine asynchronously. But what I would like to achieve is to execute the code synchronously. I would like the Java process to wait until the execution of the script is completed and then execute the next batch of code.

To summarize, I would like the "Print statement - Script executed successfully" to be executed **after** the batch file ("myscript.sh") completes execution.

Thanks

Comment: take a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code

Comment: The link talks about using Runtime.getRuntime().exec. This is also asynchronous. I am looking for a "synchronous" solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to wait for the Process to finish, that is [waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) like this

```
public void executeScript() {
  try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
      "myscript.sh");
    Process p = pb.start();     // Start the process.
    p.waitFor();                // Wait for the process to finish.
    System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The above code doesn't work if I wanted to move a file from one location to another, so I've fixed it with below code.

```
class Shell

{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/sam/myscript.sh");
      Process p = pb.start();     // Start the process.
      p.waitFor();                // Wait for the process to finish.
      System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
}


myscript.sh
#!/bin/bash   
mv -f /home/sam/Download/cv.pdf /home/sam/Desktop/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Process#waitFor()` to pause the Java code until the script terminates.  As in

```
    try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myscript.sh").start();
        int rc = p.waitFor();
        System.out.printf("Script executed with exit code %d\n", rc);
```